# Windows Server 2012 R2 - network unresponsive until reboot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

since 29th of April every day past midnight my Windows Server 2012 R2 networking hangs - AD isn't working, DNS isn't working, print server isn't working and so other services. I have to reboot server to retain functionality.

When I look from midnight into Event Logs, this Warning appears first:

> TCP/IP failed to establish an outgoing connection because the selected
> local endpoint was recently used to connect to the same remote
> endpoint. This error typically occurs when outgoing connections are
> opened and closed at a high rate, causing all available local ports to
> be used and forcing TCP/IP to reuse a local port for an outgoing
> connection. To minimize the risk of data corruption, the TCP/IP
> standard requires a minimum time period to elapse between successive
> connections from a given local endpoint to a given remote endpoint.

10 minutes after Error:

> The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network
> connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient
> condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets
> connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has successfully
> processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then
> contact your administrator.

DNS server is full of these Errors:

> Event 4015 - The description for Event ID ( 4015 ) in Source (
> Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service ) cannot be found. Either the
> component that raises this event is not installed on your local
> computer, or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair
> the component on the local computer, or contact the component
> manufacturer for a newer version.

When server is in hanged state, only 20% RAM is occupied and CPU is 1-5% - nothing suspicious.

Does anyone else experienced this? How to diagnose and solve this problem?

Comment: Already doen thebasic checks like SFC, CHKDSK and installed all windows updates and or current driver sets?

Comment: Yes. SFC and CHKDSK found and fixed nothing. Updates and drivers are all up to date.

Comment: `This error typically occurs when outgoing connections are opened and closed at a high rate`. Are connections occurring at a high rate? If so, that's the problem.